# Recursive object types in Dart?

Tags: typescript, dart, recursive-type

I should note that I'm coming from a TypeScript background which colors a lot of my perspective/nomenclature here.

In TypeScript you can define a recursive interface really easily:

```
interface User {
  name: string,
  friends: User[]
}

const bob:User = {
  name: "Bob",
  friends: []
}
```

How would you do this in Dart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not much different.

```
class User {
  String name;
  List<User> friends;
}


void main() {
  var bob = User();
  bob.name = "Bob";
  bob.friends = [User(), User(), User()];

  print(bob.name); // Bob

  print(bob.friends); // [Instance of 'User', Instance of 'User', Instance of 'User']
}
```

Comment: Well that makes a whole lotta sense. I'm not used to the class-centric approach to types, or the default nullability. Thanks!